# SQL Server 2008 Table of Customer Visits determine if Return time of a visit is less than 72 hours from previous visit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called VISITS that tracks every time a customer visits our facility. I need to find when individual customers return to our facility within 72 hours of their last departure time. I've been able to whip up the duplicate customer check based on my findings on stack overflow, but comparing the ArrivalTime column on a newer visit to a DepartureTime column on earlier visits is proving far more difficult, and I'm wondering if it's even theoretically possible.

I'm essentially having to filter down the duplicate customer IDs, then compare the DepartureTime column in one row to the ArrivalTime column in the subsequent rows. The DateDiff I realize won't serve any purpose right now, but I have that in there should I ever figure out the row1 to row 2 comparison. If possible, I'd like to eventually join to my customer name table to pull customer details, but figure I should get the big part out of the way here first.

```
SELECT AccountNumber, CustomerID, ArrivalTime, DepartureTime 
from Visits 
WHERE CustomerID IN (
    SELECT CustomerID
    FROM Visits
    GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING (COUNT(CustomerID)>1)
)
--AND DATEDIFF(hh,DepartureTime, ArrivalTime) >72 
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

UPDATE:
Thank you all for the quick responses. Per your request, here's a small data snippet. As for table structure, haha. I'm not the admin, just an implementer writing some custom reports. Our SQL tables are actually updated from PVX tables that our application accesses. The updates are sent to SQL simply on a daily basis. In short, these tables aren't built out properly. All four of these column when you run your typical describe table query have a value of NULL......

Account, Customer, Arrival Time, Departure Time

```
202353  65  2013-12-12 07:30:00.000 2013-12-11 10:21:21.710
205643  65  2014-05-08 05:30:00.000 2014-05-11 13:00:00.000
203043  211 2014-01-13 11:53:00.000 2014-01-13 23:59:00.000
204283  211 2014-03-10 11:11:00.000 2014-03-10 23:59:00.000
203846  320 2014-02-06 10:23:00.000 2014-02-06 23:59:00.000
205378  320 2014-05-19 06:52:00.000 2014-05-21 09:40:00.000
206474  320 2014-05-15 07:55:00.000 2014-05-15 23:59:00.000
203883  338 2014-02-05 14:00:00.000 2014-02-05 15:01:00.000
204000  338 2014-02-12 12:50:00.000 2014-02-12 23:59:00.000
205069  488 2014-04-16 08:00:00.000 2014-04-16 23:59:00.000
205096  488 2014-04-23 06:49:00.000 2014-04-23 23:59:00.000
204779  513 2014-03-18 13:34:00.000 2014-03-18 23:59:00.000
206060  513 2014-05-05 13:48:00.000 2014-05-05 23:59:00.000
207057  523 2014-06-05 08:04:00.000 2014-06-05 23:59:00.000
205159  523 2014-03-24 08:10:00.000 2014-03-24 23:59:00.000
202607  546 2014-01-20 11:10:00.000 2014-01-20 23:59:00.000
201178  546 2013-09-17 08:17:00.000 2013-09-17 23:59:00.000
206627  560 2014-06-02 14:52:00.000 2014-06-02 23:59:00.000
206220  560 2014-05-12 12:30:00.000 2014-05-12 23:59:00.000
205894  986 2014-05-12 05:46:00.000 2014-05-12 23:59:00.000
204177  1062    2014-02-17 06:00:00.000 2014-02-18 09:08:00.000
203669  1062    2014-02-25 09:00:00.000 2014-02-25 13:53:00.000
204858  1115    2014-03-17 06:02:00.000 2014-03-17 23:59:00.000
204861  1115    2014-03-11 09:39:00.000 2014-03-11 23:59:00.000
202437  1126    2013-12-23 07:04:00.000 2013-12-23 23:59:00.000
203126  1126    2014-01-13 06:55:00.000 2014-01-14 08:55:00.000
203502  1274    2014-01-27 12:45:00.000 2014-01-27 23:59:00.000
203033  1274    2014-01-06 14:56:00.000 2014-01-06 23:59:00.000
205346  1274    2014-04-15 11:04:00.000 2014-04-16 15:10:00.000
206675  1274    2014-06-09 13:58:00.000 2014-06-09 23:59:00.000
203673  1499    2014-02-07 07:30:00.000 2014-01-31 13:24:35.040
203674  1499    2014-02-07 05:55:00.000 2014-02-07 23:59:00.000
203634  1586    2014-02-11 09:00:00.000 2014-02-11 16:09:00.000
204296  1586    2014-02-20 06:54:00.000 2014-02-20 23:59:00.000
203549  1799    2014-03-05 09:34:00.000 2014-03-05 23:59:00.000
202471  1799    2014-01-06 12:07:00.000 2014-01-06 23:59:00.000
204057  1810    2014-02-27 07:17:00.000 2014-02-27 23:59:00.000
205136  1810    2014-03-21 07:33:00.000 2014-03-21 23:59:00.000
205452  1903    2014-04-11 11:00:00.000 2014-04-07 16:34:41.533
205468  2312    2014-04-21 07:30:00.000 2014-04-17 07:46:56.433
205217  2312    2014-04-07 11:29:00.000 2014-04-07 16:31:00.000
205807  2312    2014-05-05 09:00:00.000 2014-04-22 17:54:51.603
204001  2496    2014-02-17 10:26:00.000 2014-02-17 23:59:00.000
203600  2496    2014-02-05 12:00:00.000 2014-02-05 15:03:00.000
201734  2605    2013-11-07 10:57:00.000 2013-11-08 17:28:00.000
204646  2605    2014-04-18 07:52:00.000 2014-04-18 23:59:00.000
206027  2905    2014-05-30 06:27:00.000 2014-05-30 23:59:00.000
206802  2905    2014-06-05 05:55:00.000 2014-06-05 23:59:00.000
```

Comment: Perhaps a join which would join the table with itself could prove to be profitable when comparing the departure to the latest arrival. Do you have some sample data to provide along with your table structure so that one could SQL Fiddle to find out?

Comment: You could also solve this with a WHERE EXISTS() clause, I'm not sure which would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you self-join on

```
SELECT v1.AccountNumber, v1.CustomerID, v1.ArrivalTime, v1.DepartureTime 
from Visits v1
  INNER JOIN Visits v2
    ON v1.customerId = v2.customerId
    AND v2.ArrivalTime > v1.DepartureTime
    AND v2.ArrivalTime != v1.ArrivalTime
WHERE DATEDIFF(hh,v1.DepartureTime, v2.ArrivalTime) >72
```

I know I am missing something, but that seems like it might get you started. This would allow you to skip the inner  group by. Rows would not join to themselves -- they would only join to 2nd and 3rd and 4th visits. I am not certain what you want to do with those, so I can't guess yet if you need to make sure that it is only the consecutive visits. That is, if there are only 2 visits this might work. With more than 2, it has issues.

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours fighting with multiple subqueries here, and never though to JOIN on the table. This certainly has given me a lot to work with.